# android JNI ERROR

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, java-native-interface

I'm developping a cordova / phonegap android plugin to list wifi around the device.

Into my plugin class, i want to use the WifiManager to do the work. 
  Here my execute method :

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    Log.d ("WifiLister", "action : "  + action);
    if ("WifiList".equals(action)) {
        wifiList(callbackContext);          
        return true;
    }
    return false;  // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
}
```

Here my wifiList method :

```
private void wifiList(CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException{        
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) cordova.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);        
    if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {     
        callbackContext.error("Wifi disabled, please turn on Wifi and try again");
    }
    else{
          // do something
   }
```

on the isWifiEnabled method call, i got the following error :

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1
VM aborting
fatal signal 11 (SISEGC) at 0Xdeadd00d (code=1)
```

I read found the same error with people who wants to make native (C/C++) code into android app, and they have to use the newGlobalRef method to . But it' not my case, i'm in pure java code.

Any one can help?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/phonegap/U5U5X07bEUI/TG4VppzazfQJ - it might be a permissions issue.

Comment: thanks,it needed android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE for me. even if I don't use it. maybe a phonegap strange issue with some device.